# Why is stat mech involved in mean field theory?

Tags: field-theory, perturbation-theory, approximations

Mean field theory involves approximating an interacting system by a non-interacting one, by replacing some operators with their expectation value. However, to my surprise, free energy is involved in the process. I wonder, why should stat mech be involved at all?

In perturbation theory, another approximation method, we also approximate an interacting system, but stat mech is not mentioned. Approximation methods and statistical methods should be separate entities, so I wonder why they must coincide.

Comment: Mean field theory usually means that one replaces the interactions in an n-body system with an effective field that acts on one of the particles, i.e. one assumes that the effect of n-1 particles can be reduced to a much more simple averaged force (or potential). This is done by stochastic averaging (spatial and temporal), but operators need not be involved, at all, unless you are talking about quantum field theory? Perturbation theory usually replaces the direct solution of a system with the iterative solution of its perturbations, which can be done for stochastic and non-stochastic systems.

Comment: If you want to use mean-field theory to calculate ground state properties, then you do not need free energy, but still need to look at ground state energy (minimizing it with regard to the variational parameters). Now if you want to understand how the system behaves at finite temperature, free energy naturally comes in. In the end of the day, you are dealing with a many-body system and want to understand its macroscopic behavior. Why is it surprising that stat mech is involved? Stat mech was invented exactly for this kind of problems!